# iOS Metal - simplify / optimize algorithm (point line distance)

Tags: ios, algorithm, optimization, metal

I'm creating an iOS app using Metal. In my app, I have particles that can be manipulated by touching the display of the device. Each particle has an x and y (and z and w, but those are not important here) and there are "gravity wells" for each touching finger (z == 1 means the touch is active). Every particle gets updated each time the `drawRect` in my `Particles.swift` (subclass of `MTKView`) is called - this happens in my `Particle.metal` file.

If two fingers touch the display, an invisible line is created between the two points of touch. Every particle close enough to this line is moved away perpendicularly to the line. Unfortunately, I'm suspecting that this kind of manipulation (or the calculation of it) results in an CPU-overload on older devices (like iPhone 5s and sometimes on iPhone 6), which results in flickering of the whole screen (iPhone 6) or even deletion of all the particles on the screen (iPhone 5s).

Here is the current algorithm for the two-finger-manipulation of my particles: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/SYdRvjak). At first, I calculate the distance between my particle and the "invisible line". If the distance is lower than some value, the position of the particle is manipulated. This is done for each particle that is visible on the screen.

I was wondering if anyone can suggest any optimization / simplification tips.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Any reason you included a pastebin instead of the actual code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of using a separate compute shader to draw a linear gradient along that line and using that texture to control the direction of the particles? I have a project, [ParticleCam](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/ParticleCam), that uses the luma value of a live camera feed to attract particles towards the lighter areas of an image. If you passed that shader an image of a linear gradient, you may achieve what you're after.